# How to detect when reopen an app sleeping in background on iOS (Firemonkey)?

Tags: firemonkey

I want to use TouchID to protect an application.

The TouchID function,(implemented in Activate event) work corect if i start (a closed) application.

But nothing happened when i reactivate same application from background (is already opened in background).

Any ideea on how to detect which event i have to use to capture reactivation of an open application on iOS (firemonkey) ?

Any help will be apreciated !

Comment: The "TApplicationEvent.WillBecomeForeground" is fired when the app returns from background.

Comment: Great
Many thanks !